# Is it conceptually possible to create a javascript bookmarklet to copy and paste html form entries?

Tags: javascript, forms, copy-paste, bookmarklet

I think this is what they are talking about on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348227/javascript-bookmarklet-to-take-info-from-one-page-and-submit-it-to-form-on-anothe), but I'm not sure.

What I am looking for is a bookmarklet I can add to the toolbar of my browser, like [the ones on this page](http://operawiki.info/BookMarklets#forms). This hypothetical script would work much like the Windows clipboard, except that it would copy an entire set of entries in a web form with the click of one button, and then paste those same entries back into a second form with identical fields, on a different website.

The closest I've been able to find to what I want is [this Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5873/), which looks like it would be perfect, except that it's browser dependent, which wouldn't be a dealbreaker. But in fact it's been abandoned and won't even work in the latest version of Firefox any more, so it's pretty much useless.

I don't know enough about javascript to know if this is even possible in theory, hence this question.

Answer (score 1):

The part of pasting what's copied to a second identified source with it's own form fields may not be possible. A bookmarklet for extracting the values of a form may be easily found.

http://ostermiller.org/bookmarklets/

I'm attempting something similar, via bookmarklet would be nice but I settled for the firefox addons. Please share if you've found a better solution.

This link says Opera also has a built in capability to insert greasmonkey scripts. http://my.opera.com/thibi/blog/firefox-to-opera

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's possible - you would need cross-domain scripting for that. You could put it in the real clipoard (json-encoded or so), but that's not possible in all/most browsers for security reasons. What I could imagine is making a javascript-popup with the json-encoded data that the user could copy or so after reading the form data and a javascript input that pops up when "pasting" that asks you to press CTRL+V.

Why don't you make it an add-on?

Comment: I can't make it at all, my programming skills just aren't up to it. I'm just trying to get an idea here of what is possible and how difficult it might be.

Comment: (continued) before I go out and try to hire a freelancer to do it for me.

I thought it would be possible in javascript because some of the bookmarklets on that page I linked to clearly are doing things to forms, like that "autofill anonymous". 

But if it can't be done with JavaScript, could that abandoned Firefox addon I linked to be adapted to use with Opera? Or should I ask that in another thread?

Comment: PPS: How do you do a newline in this thing? I hit enter and my fragment of a comment got posted...

Comment: @user513845: The difficult part is transferring data between different domains - if the pages come from the same domain (is that the case?), it's possible, but as soon as that isn't the case, you have to do it from a higher access-level - browser add-ons have it. Oh, as far as I know, you can't make newlines in comments, just in questions and answers.

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on this idea of using popups? I'm having trouble visualizing what you're describing.

Comment: No they are not the same domains. I thought javascript could store the data, in a cookie perhaps or however it is the autfill bookmarklet does, and then later retrieve it...

Comment: @user513845: Cookies are always limited to one domain. But doing it using, for example, a Greasemonkey script should be possible. Here is an example - however, I don't know whether it's exactly what you need: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/66442

Comment: I tried the greasemonkey script, it also will only work on one domain. I also managed to try that Firefox addon I linked to on an old version of FF and it worked very nicely except that it wouldn't copy form fields with input type=file. So I know what I want is possible, but I'm still at a loss on how to get it. If I wanted to hire a freelancer to adapt that Firefox addon to work in Opera, what tags would I use for the post?