# Storing data client-side from one page to fill out a form on the other site

Tags: javascript, forms, post, bookmarklet, cross-site

I'd like to help the visitors to my site to fill out a form on the other site (beyond control) using the data, generated on my site.

It would be possible to use a bookmarklet to post the data to the form while the user is on my site, but the form is some clicks behind the authentication. Considering that a bookmarklet may read only what's been stored (cookie, session, storage) while on the current site, it is not possible to use the bookmarklet on the other site to fill out the form with data, stored while on my site.

Please, suggest any javascript, client-side solutions of this. Like a bookmarklet or something similar.

Thank you.

Comment: can you use server-side, or strictly client side?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348227/javascript-bookmarklet-to-take-info-from-one-page-and-submit-it-to-form-on-anoth?rq=1

Comment: @Markasoftware 1) there's no answer there. 2) ok. let's suppose server-side is possible. how then?

Comment: Well that's only if you are able to have server side stuff on both of the servers, and if you don't have access to the other one I really doubt that

Comment: i do not control the other one.

Answer (score 0):

With a bookmarklet I'd say you're on the right track, but use a dynamic one. e.g:

```
function makeBookmarklet(){
    var elt=document.createElement('a');
    var hrefString='';
    for(var k=0;k<arguments.length;k++){
        hrefString+=' document.getElementById("'+arguments[k].id+'").value="'+arguments[k].value+'";';
    }
    elt.href=hrefString;
    return elt;
}
```

And then you would call that function, and each argument should be an object with an `id` and `value` attribute. The `id` should be the id of the field to automatically fill out. `value` should be the value to insert into that field. It returns an element, so put it somewhere in the document and tell the user to drag it into the bookmarks bar, and click it on the other site. Just to make it clearer, you would call it like this:

```
aElt=makeBookmarklet({id:'username',value:document.getElementById('username').value},{id:'othercrap',value:'fixedvalue'});
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. i am not sure i understand the finer points. are you suggesting storing data in the bookmarklet and asking my visitors to install a new bookmarklet every time they generate some data they want to post behind an authentication on the other site (i do not control, but have access to)?

Comment: They would have to have a new bookmarklet every time for this, yes. Also, does the other server have CORS enabled? Are you able to put JavaScript into the other webpage? If either of those are possible, I could make a much more convenient way to do this.

Comment: 1) no info on cors. 2) i can not add anything to the site where the form is.

Comment: if we consider a bookmarklet can GET and POST anywhere, then, maybe i can naturally store the data the user generates on my site anywhere serverside (mysql or whatever) and then, while she's on the other site and is about to fill the form out, he clicks the bookmarklet and, since the bookmarklet is allowed to GET and POST anywhere, the bookmarklet would read the necessary data off my site. is this possible? how?

Comment: You can't bypass the same origin policy, but you could use JSONP or postMessage. postMessage would probably be easier, but it's HTML5. JSONP would have wider browser support. I'll edit my answer sooner or later, don't have time right now